# passing mysql account to remote server

Tags: php, mysql

i've got to connect 2 php pages on 2 different servers,

in the first server there's the DB (mysql) with an "email" table, generated by a php page..
in the second server there's a php file wich needs to read the "email" table...

the second php page doesn't need to be opened by the user

the fact is that i need to make this work with lots of DB, not just one
so i can't store the mysql connection params in the php page on the 2nd server and just open it... i've got to pass the connection params every time

For now i use something like this, on the 1st server php page:

```
$socketcon = fsockopen("http://www.server2.com",80,$errorno,$errorstr,10);

if($socketcon) { 
  $socketdata = "GET page2.php?dbuser=xxx&dbpass=xxx&db=xxx  HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: http://www.server2.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
  fwrite($socketcon,$socketdata); 
  fclose($socketcon); 
}
```

but i fear that putting the params in URL is soooo bad....

any idea ?

Comment: In general passing database access credentials over unecnrypted channel is soooo bad.....

Comment: Is it possible to construct on server 2 a database of database credentials?  Although I know you said you cannot store params on 2nd server it seems this is more reasonable approach so as you do not need to communicate these details across the nets.

Comment: no, i don't have access to dbs on the 2nd server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do is to create a "public" webservice with PHP that will receive credentials. If the credentials match you reply with the data you need (maybe in XML format). Of course all of this is over HTTPS. You can then "talk" with the service with [CURL](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to create you DB connexion.

Comment: hmm, since i can't store anything on the second server, i'll have to use the same credentials for every connection i have to make...and is passing db credentials by curl more secure ?

Comment: It will be more secure if you use CURL over an HTTPS connection.

Comment: is doing the fsockopen() through ssl and sending data in POST form a viable option ?

Comment: Yes it's pretty the same thing. In my exprerience it's just that CURL is more often enabled that the http/https wrappers for fopen & friends (at least in the hosts I've worked with).